# Get data from a endpoint and store it in a csv

Tags: python, list, api, csv

I want to get data from a endpoint. That stores it in a dataframe and convert it in a csv. It gets the data after each time interval but it keeps replacing the values in same row instead of storing all the values in csv.

```py
import requests
import threading
import csv
import json
interval = 3
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def myPeriodicFunction():
    r=requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json").json()

    df=json_normalize(r['bpi']['USD'])

    df.to_csv('data.csv',sep='\t', header=True)

def startTimer():
    threading.Timer(interval, startTimer).start()
    myPeriodicFunction()

startTimer()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def myPeriodicFunction():
    r=requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json").json()

    df=json_normalize(r['bpi']['USD'])
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f,sep='\t', header=False)
```